# Tableau turning my duration data into date data

Tags: tableau-desktop

I'm just trying to make a simple line chart in Tableau Desktop from some very simple data.

[Data in Google Sheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvTTD.png)

The Date Row is formatted as Plain Text.
The members and casual riders rows are formatted as 'Duration'.

However, when I DL the data to my pc and then add this data to Tableau, Tableau is turning my duration data into Calendar data for some reason.

[What it looks like in Tableau](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hz9xY.png)

Not sure why it's doing that, but it's stopping me from making what should be a very easy line chart.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your data needs to be cleaned before loading to Tableau, I could explain the steps in detail, but I need access to your data to show you

Comment: @Debayan, thank you for your reply. How do I go about getting you a copy of the spreadsheet?

Comment: share a google sheet link maybe

Comment: @Debayan here's a link to a copy of my original spreadsheet. It has the same data.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fRrPvNdLVI4o9EObx2VMn5p3jHrQIax55Lda3XtVZUg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks, I will explain my answer in detail and keep the files in this link : https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1spsw6DRE9LY5RTdjekKZAjimS8SnPYsI?usp=sharing

Comment: in case you have issues implementing, we can setup a 1-to-1 session

Comment: @Debayan, thank you, I will give it a go at my next opportunity and let you know how I go.

Comment: @Debayan, 

After a bit of research it seems that Tableau is very fussy about the data that it accepts. 

My data is not in the best format for Tableau.

So basically that's my question answered.

I think I'll leave this here for the time-being and figure out the rest on my own, as all good learners should. 

Thanks for all your help and advice with this question.

Comment: Tableau Desktop coupled with Tableau Prep can resolve almost all your data analytics/engineering problems and they are easy to use. Happy Learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be really useful to utilize the Data Cleaning options from Tableau Prep

If you open the .tflx file, you will understand that I applied certain steps to obtain a cleaned dataset, you may rename the columns as required.
In the last step, you can either save the output dataset as a Tableau .Hyper file or an xlsx/csv file

Download Tableau Prep (it uses same license as tableau)

[image]